# Crash when debugging flutter apps: com.android.build.gradle.internal.crash.PluginCrashReporter

Tags: flutter, dart, gradle

I am trying to debugging my app in android emulator, but I got error log like this

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/data/data/appsOk/android/app/build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not initialize class com.android.build.gradle.internal.crash.PluginCrashReporter

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

here is my app/build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion "28.0.3"

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    lintOptions {
        disable 'InvalidPackage'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.hello.myapps"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

  

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            // signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    api 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision-face-model:17.0.2'

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.1"
    implementation "android.arch.core:common:1.1.1"
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:9.6.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

is there a way to solve this case ?

Comment: Android Studio -> File -> Invalidate Caches / Restart... -> Invalidate and Restart
And then gradle sync

Answer (score 0):

this is a very strange issue, it also happen in my project, I solved it after dropdown my Gradle version(even if the old version works well before this issue happen), I don't know why, but now it works.

before:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip
```

after:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.5-all.zip
```